# Capturing values from html table using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to capture the values present inside the table cells (td tags) using JQuery and pass it to ajax request.

```
<div id="table">
  <table id="table2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Total Fat</td>
        <td id="totalFat">26.3g</td>
        <td>Carb.</td>
        <td id="carb">8.8g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sat. Fat</td>
        <td id="satFat">1.8g</td>
        <td>Fiber</td>
        <td id="fiber">6.7g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Carter</td>
        <td id="carter">0g</td>
        <td>Sugar</td>
        <td id="sugar">3.5g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cholest.</td>
        <td id="cholestral">304.5g</td>
        <td>Protein</td>
        <td id="protein">10.5g</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Ajax request code for sending the request

```
function foodLog() {
  var data = {
    carbs : $('#carb').text(),
    totalFat : $('#totalFat').val(),
    saturatedFat : $('#satFat').val(),
    carter : $('#carter').val(),
    fiber : $('#fiber').val(),
    cholestral : $('#cholestral').val(),
    sugar : $('#sugar').val(),
  };

  $.ajax({  
    type : "POST",   
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url : "/fitbase/foodlog/create",
    dataType: "json",
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    success : function(response) {  
      alert(response);
    },  
    error : function(e) {  
      alert('Error: ' + e);   
    }  
  });  
};
```

But I am not able to get those values nested inside the table cells.

Comment: And where are you stuck?

Comment: I want to take those values in ajax request,function foodLog(){
       var data={
       servings : $('#servings').val(),
       protein :   $('#protein').val(),
       calories :  $('#calories h4').text(),
       carbs : $('#carb').text(),
          totalFat : $('#totalFat').val(),
       saturatedFat : $('#saturatedFat').val(),
       carter : $('#carter').val(),
       fiber : $('#fiber').val(),
       cholestral : $('#cholestral').val(),
       sugar : $('#sugar').val(),
       size : $('#size').val(),
       };

Comment: Which doesn't appear to be mentioned in your question. You might want to provide a full explanation of what you want, what you tried yourself and where your own attempts failed (what did your code *not* do that it should have, and what did it *do* that it should not have done?).

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
var totalFat = $("#totalFat").text();
var carb = $("#carb").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.val()` with `.text()`:

```
function foodLog() {
  var data = {
    carbs : $('#carb').text(),
    totalFat : $('#totalFat').text(),
    saturatedFat : $('#satFat').text(),
    carter : $('#carter').text(),
    fiber : $('#fiber').text(),
    cholestral : $('#cholestral').text(),
    sugar : $('#sugar').text(),
  };

  $.ajax({  
    type : "POST",   
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url : "/fitbase/foodlog/create",
    dataType: "json",
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    success : function(response) {  
      alert(response);
    },  
    error : function(e) {  
      alert('Error: ' + e);   
    }  
  });  
};
```

Comment: I changed then also same problem mate

Answer (score 0):

As chipChocolate.py pointed out above, switching from `.val()` to `.text()` worked, only after including jquery in the file. I had a similar problem.

To reproduce, I setup the following in a file, and loaded it in a browser:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table">
  <table id="table2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Total Fat</td>
        <td id="totalFat">26.3g</td>
        <td>Carb.</td>
        <td id="carb">8.8g</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Without including the javascript on the top line above, the following did not work, but after including it, `.text()` and `.html()` seemed to return what was in the td:

[image: proof of concept in browser]